# Deprecation of all previous Azure Application Insights NuGet packages

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-application-insights

All previous versions, of the various Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.* packages on nuget.org have all switched to being deprecated. This feels unusual for a minor release, and it's not acknowledged in the release notes. Is there a reason for this?

[image]

e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question for anyone else that might be wondering if they *need* to upgrade Application Insights packages, the short answer is no. You can keep on using the version you are on with the usual consideration for the patch and minor release notes.

This is a recent move by the Application Insights team to comply with the [Azure SDK lifecycle and support policy](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/policies_support.html#package-lifecycle) that states:

> or has been superseded by a more recent release. In both cases, the current library is deprecated in favor of a newer library.

The main driver, is that support requests are typically resolved by updating to the latest SDK version, so only 'supporting' the latest version ensures we all try that first before teams commit resources to support.

Source: [Application Insights GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2607).